# Quering one table and ordering by occurences from another

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, grouping

I need to select all my comments from the 'comments' talbe. the thing is, each comment receive multiple 'likes' which are stored in the 'likes' table.

I would like to select all the items from the 'comments' table, but order then by the number of likes when each 'like' is represented as a row in the 'likes' table...

does anyone know a good way to do this?
thanks so much,
Yanipan
** edit **
Hi,
you are correct, sorry.
I use php as my server side, and MySql as my database...
I forgot how wide is the range of questions asked on this forum...

Comment: You've managed to ask the question, and tag it, without once mentioning what technologies are involved, or at what layer you're writing your query. Is an ORM involved? Or is it purely in SQL. If SQL, which server?

Comment: Hi,
you are correct, sorry.
I use php as my server side, and MySql as my database...
I forgot how wide is the range of questions asked on this forum...

Comment: you can use joins , but we can't help you too much if you don't let us know exactly the create table statements for the to tables . Allso you can ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com where all database administrators hang out so you'll get a better answer there .

Answer (score 0):

Fetching 10 most liked comments, including those without any likes at all (left join) (assuming a simple structure with two tables: comments and likes):

```
select c.*,count(l.id) as likes
  from comments c 
    left join likes l on c.id = l.comment 
  group by l.comment
  order by count(l.id) desc 
  limit 10;
```

Note that the performance of this query will be pretty nasty though. Hence you'll most likely have to find another strategy to sort your comments by number of likes.

Comment: thanks, it really does work. as for your advice, I really did made an update query to the comments table when there is a vote, so there is a sum of all votes for each comment. it means another query for each vote, but at least it saves time and cpu later... thanks for your advice!

Comment: @yanipan as you are new here: you should accept correct answers to your questions: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)" http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask